# Google Colab files are gone

Tags: google-colaboratory

Just spent like 8 hours coding in colab. I coded many python files and saved them on this files tab, under sample data but not in sample data. Got off and came back reopened the browser and all my files are gone!

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess this question is more about venting, right?!

Because there is nothing to do, as far as I know.

Obvious tip for next time, use Google Drive to store your scripts.

Playground only provides temporary session, so in order to save any changes, notebook files must be saved.

The easiest way to save Colab notebook is to save it in your Google Drive. Click File > Save a copy in Drive. Once you saved a copy of this tutorial, you can open it from your Google Drive or Colab dashboard

To mount Google Drive, run the below code and go to the link to retrieve the authorization code

```
 from google.colab import drive
 
 drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Once mounted successfully, your entire Google Drive files should be accessible under /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/

```
 !ls /content/gdrive/My\ Drive
```

[How to use Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YKHHLSlG-B9Ez2-zf-YFxXTVgfC_Aqtt)

Comment: Hi. I am suffering from same issue. Came across this question so commenting in place of opening new question. I have tried saving in drive and then loading from drive but the files brought from git through code and then those i create from my notebook all gone. i had to re-run python code every time. Even not saving in drive. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well this might be a little late but...I just had the same issue as you and I fixed it. I just disconnected/reconnected my Google Drive and refreshed the browser. There is that folder icon in the folder tree with the google drive icon on it. Worth a shot...